# How to get date from mongoDB and display it, using moment.js?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date, momentjs, utc

I have a form where the user inputs the date in the following format: YYYY-MM-DD

I store the date in Mongo DB. By default, Mongo DB stores it as a UTC Date.

Example:
User inputs 2018-02-06
Mongo stores: "Tue Feb 06 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)"

Lets say I want to display this date back to the user.

The following code gives me the wrong date:

```
var eventDateString = $('#hiddenDate').val() // Just gets the date as stored in mongo
var dateObj = new Date(eventDateString)
var dateMom = moment(dateObj).format('dddd, MMMM DD YYYY');
console.log(dateMom)
```

What gets printed is:
"Monday, February 05 2018" 
This is incorrect, the date should be Feb 6.

Why is this happening?

I tried to solve the issue by doing this:

```
var eventDateString = $('#hiddenDate').val();
$('#show-eventDate').text(moment.utc(eventDateString).format('dddd, MMMM DD YYYY'));
```

I get the correct Result: "Tuesday, February 06 2018"

However, I get the following warning:

[image]

*(Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info....)*

How do I get around this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are quite close to solution, you have to use [`moment.utc`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) to tell moment that your input is UTC and pass [format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) argument to avoid *Deprecation Warning*.

Code sample:

```js
var eventDateString = $('#hiddenDate').val();
var mom = moment.utc(eventDateString, 'ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ'); 
$('#show-eventDate').text(mom.format('dddd, MMMM DD YYYY'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<input id="hiddenDate" type="hidden" value="Tue Feb 06 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)">
<div id="show-eventDate"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a small edit to VincenzoC's response

instead of moment(eventDate....), the correct solution has moment.utc(.....)

```
var eventDateString = $('#hiddenDate').val();
var mom = moment.utc(eventDateString, 'ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ'); 
$('#show-eventDate').text(mom.format('dddd, MMMM DD YYYY'));
```

Comment: I've edited my aswer to fix snippet and I was aware of `moment.utc` since I suggested to use it in the first part of my answer (I just forgot to use it in the snippet). I really don't undertstand why you marked as accepted your first answer and why you posted this new answer instead of commenting mine or propose an edit to it.

Comment: Sorry. I'm new to this

Answer (score 0):

This Worked Perfectly for Me

```
moment(req.body.foo , "ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ").format("DD/MM/YYYY");
```

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more about why this works, and why this is a good choice?

Answer (score -1):

So I did this to avoid the depreciation warning, and it worked

```
var eventDateString = $('#hiddenDate').val();
var index = eventDateString.indexOf('00:00');
var shortDate = eventDateString.substr(0,index-1);
$('#show-eventDate').text(moment(shortDate, 'ddd MMM DD YYYY').format('dddd, MMMM DD YYYY'));
```

But I don't like the idea that I'm hardcoding '00:00' -- any better solution would be appreciated